# App Domain for Facebook integrated Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What should I enter for 'App Domains' in configuring my Facebook App ( developers.facebook.com)? I'm developing an Android App using Xamarin. I run the app in the Android SDK Emulator. There is no URL as near as I can tell.

Error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL (What?) or Canvas URL (What? What?), or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. (what? what? what?)

I'm running in an Emulator, which is the standard way to do development. There has to be a way to configure the Facebook API to accept my requests from the emulator.  Anyone dealt with this problem before? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

App Domain is not necessary/required, you can left it...!

Facebook sdk does not require the app domain and it works fine without it,

But if you want to fill it, you can use the application's website domain address for example http://www.google.com .